# Html.Dropdown - get the value of each option to be the same as the text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do something simple - I'm starting to learn MVC and I'm getting a tad confused. I have a dropdown that produces the following

```
<selectid="selectMenu" name="selectMenu">
<option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
<option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
<option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
<option value="Annually">Annually</option>
</select>
```

thus I added the following to my view -

```
<% string[] rate = new string[]{"Weekly","Monthly","Quarterly","Annually"}; %>
<%: Html.DropDownList("selectMenu", new SelectList(rate))%>
```

However this produced the following:

```
<select DataTextField="" DataValueField="" Items="System.String[]" SelectedValue="" SelectedValues="" id="selectMenu" name="selectMenu">
<option>Weekly</option>
<option>Monthly</option>
<option>Quarterly</option>
<option>Annually</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the value of each option to be the same as the text?

Perhaps I should stick to JavaScript?

Comment: Is that the exact html that is being rendered in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% var rate = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Weekly", "Weekly" }, { "Monthly", "Monthly" }, { "Quarterly", "Quarterly" }, { "Annually", "Annually" } }; } %>

<%: Html.DropDownList("selectMenu", new SelectList(rate, "Key", "Value"), "--please select--") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a loop and not use a html helper (syntax might be off)

```
<select id="selectMenu" name="selectMenu">
<% string[] rates = new string[]{"Weekly","Monthly","Quarterly","Annually"}; %>
<% foreach (string rate in rates) { %>
   <option value="<%: rate %>"><%: rate %></option>
<% } %>
</select>
```

If your just starting out, I'd recommend using the Razor View engine in asp.net-mvc3.  The syntax would be:

```
<select id="selectMenu" name="selectMenu">
@( string[] rates = new string[]{"Weekly","Monthly","Quarterly","Annually"}; )
@foreach (string rate in rates)
{
   <option value="@rate">@rate</option>
}
</select>
```